# VirtualEnv apache2 server No module named 'django'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, apache, mod-wsgi

I am running a virtual environment for my apache2 server from inside `/home/myname/myproject/venv`

I activate my virtual environment with

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Running

```
which django-admin
```

Returns the correct file from inside my virtual environment.

Running

```
 import django
 django.__file__
```

Returns

```
/home/myname/myproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py
```

Running

```
pip freeze
```

Returns all of my needed packages.

I also have my apache2 config file pointing to the venv directory with the python-path argument

However, after restarting the server I'm still getting a ModuleNotFoundError for django.

What's the issue here?

EDIT: apache2 config file

```
    Alias /static /home/myname/myproject/static
    <Directory /home/myname/myproject/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /media /home/myname/myproject/media
        <Directory /home/myname/myproject/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

    <Directory /home/myname/myproject/myproj>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/myname/myproject/myproj/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject_app python-path=/home/myname/myproject python-home=/home/myname/myproject/venv/
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject_app
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

#os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproj.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: You need to show that Apache config.

Comment: Are you sure that you activate `virtualenv` when restart your apache server? Could you add to the post `wsgi.py` file as well as Apache config?

Comment: Updated the original post with the config

Comment: Also yes, I made sure to activate the venv

Comment: @BrandonHimes It doesn't seem so. As far as I see your code. You do point to virtualenv folder but where do you activate it in code?

Comment: @DmytroChasovskyi how do I activate it for apache2?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add activation of virtual environment to `wsgi.py` file.

```
import os
import sys

PROJECT_DIR = '/home/myname/myproject'
sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_DIR)


def execfile(filename):
    globals = dict( __file__ = filename )
    exec( open(filename).read(), globals )

activate_this = os.path.join( PROJECT_DIR, 'venv/bin', 'activate_this.py' )
execfile( activate_this )
```

This code should be before `django` import. Otherwise, whenever you restart `Apache2`, you will need to manually activate virtual environment.

**NOTE:** make sure that you have all requirements install in virtual environment.

Comment: But I do manually activate the virtual environment whenever i restart the server, and still receive the same error. I don't understand why my virtualenv recognizes django but apache does not even though it points to the same virtualenv

Comment: @BrandonHimes could you verify that if you apply the above changes your code still will give an error? The problem is not in `Apache2` but in your code, how your code should know that it has to use virtualenv?

Comment: Yes, I added your changes and receive the same error.

Comment: Can you add the whole log from `/var/log/apache2/error.log`?

Comment: @BrandonHimes can you also add `pip freeze` of activated virtual environment?

Comment: Any solution @BrandonHimes?